# Background Images in the Right Orthographic Viewport Disproportionate to the Other Views

Tags: 3d-view

I noticed that when I put a Background Image in the Right Orthographic View port it is disproportionate to the other view ports. I know the sizes are correct, I've measured them in Photoshop and my computer tells me the sizes are correct but when I put them in Blender, the Top and Front view are proportionate but the right view is always off. I try resizing it but it's not a matter of it being too small, it's completely disproportionate to the other views. Any ideas?[image: The Right Orthographic Viewport is significantly disproportionate to the other views.]

---

@brasshat
I did something similar. I had originally made an orthographic projection, that's how I know all of my measurements were right, but instead of uploading the individual images as separate jpgs into the Background Image I just imported the Orthographic Projection file directly. That seems to work, however, I have to move the image in each viewport so that they line up, but the sizes are accurate now, I just don't seem to understand why it wouldn't do it with individual jpgs.
[image]

I went ahead and put my idividual jpgs on top. Note that I did nothing to these jpgs that would change their size but this is what I get.
[image]

Notice that Blender is changing the sizes of the individual jpgs but leaving the psd file alone. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to the site, NIck. I'd suggest you take the [tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help), especially the parts about asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 1):

The way I deal with this is to take the three views of the object, and normalize them to the same size. Lets suppose I have the dimensions of the images of item are that the top view is 1000 pixels long by 800 pixels wide, the dimensions of the front view are 1000 pixels long by 1200 pixels tall, and the dimensions of the end view are 800 pixels wide x 1200 pixels tall. In Photoshop (R) [NB: for the record, I don't use photoshop, and do this in GIMP, but it is beyond the realm of my imagination that you can't do the same thing in photoshop] I create a canvas using the maximum of the dimensions of all three, plus a border, so I'd create a base image size (in GIMP, a "canvas") measuring 1100 x 1300 pixels. I'd make three copies of this image, and into one I'd place (so that the center of the desired part of the image is at the center of the canvas) the top view, in a second I'd place the front view, and in the third, I'd place the end view. The amount of border around the three images will vary, but the parts of the Blender image in each viewport should be both the same perceived size, and the same actual size.

I don't usually "waste" the borders around the images, either. Using the image processing software, I'll usually edit into the borders of the background images things like scales and useful dimensions not already provided, or readily apparent, in the drawing.